# Parse URL with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

Given a url `(https://www.stackoverflow.com/path-to-question)`, I am wondering if there is a way to parse the url to get its components in AppleScript/AppleScriptObjC directly (without using e.g. Javascript) and set them as variables; those components being:

- protocol (i.e. `https` or `http`)
- host (e.g. `www.stackoverflow.com`)
- pathname (e.g. `path-to-question`)

I know one can do this via Javascript using

```
l = window.location
protocol = l.protocol
host = l.host
path = l.pathname
```

**What I am trying to do:**
What I am trying to do is, given a current tab with URL `(https://www.stackoverflow.com/path-to-question)`, change its URL to something like `(https://(MY_TEXT1)-www.stackoverflow.com_(MY_TEXT2)/path-to-question_(MY_TEXT3))`

Any help with how to do this via AppleScript directly would be much appreciated

Comment: Is AppleScriptObjC allowed?

Comment: @vadian Yes, indeed it is

Comment: If you coerce a URL string to class `URL`, this provides some easily accessible and useful properties, e.g. `the host's DNS form`.  It can identify most common schemes (protocols), but enumerates these using AppleScript constants, which can be annoying.  But provided the URL string starts with `"http://"` or `"https://"`, then `word 1` will provide the scheme (without the `"://"`).  Thus `tell urlString as URL to get word 1 & "://" & the host's DNS form & "/"` gives everything before the path.

Comment: @CJK Thank you for your comment. Yes that would be nice to do. I am currently trying to extract the URL within a `tell current tab` environment, and within it, for some reason I am not able to perform the following: `set myURL to URL as URL`. I am new to AppleScript and therefore am likely missing something here.

Comment: That's because Chrome (I presume it's Chrome you're using) has a property named `"URL"`, which clashes with the AppleScript class also called `"URL"`.  Since you're inside a Chrome `tell` block, the compiler assumes by default that all terminology pertains to Chrome, and thus can't make sense of the instruction to coerce a value to a class that's actually a named property.  You simply need to do the two steps separately: 1) A Chrome `tell` block: `tell app "Google Chrome" to tell the active tab of the front window to set myURL to the URL`; 2) 
Outside the block: `set myURL to myURL as URL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help to the [Foundation framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlcomponents?language=objc) it's pretty easy

```
set urlString to "https://www.stackoverflow.com/path-to-question"
set urlComponents to my (NSURLComponents's componentsWithString: urlString)
tell urlComponents
    set urlScheme to |scheme|() as text
    set urlHost to |host|() as text
    set urlPath to |path|() as text
end tell
```

If you need to omit the leading slash in the path just write

```
set urlPath to text 2 thru -1 of (|path|() as text)
```